# Derivative of a changing function

Tags: calculus

I have the following question. Now I now calculus but somehow I am not able to find a satsifying answer. Let's suppose I have a function of $x(t)$ and in addition the function itself is changing over time, and let's suppose I model that writing my function as

$$
Q(t) = f(x(t),t)
$$
I would like to calculate the derivative of the function and isolate the two contributions, one from $x(t)$ and the other from the change of the function itself. How would you do it?
I know I can write
$$
\frac{dQ(t)}{dt}=\frac{dQ(t)}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
but I really would like to be able to distinguish the two contributions. Can someone shed some light on the problem? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance, Umberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the chain rule and partial derivatives.  $$\frac {dQ(t)}{dt}=\frac {\partial f(x(t),t)}{\partial x(t)}\frac {dx(t)}{dt}+\frac {\partial f(x(t),t)}{\partial t}$$
where the second partial is only acting on the second argument of $f$.

Comment: Easy enough... Thanks!